# SUMIF Returning Zero 0 - Checked everything

Tags: excel

I have a really simple table and I'm trying to use SUMIF to sum the numbers in column B based on a list of salaries in column A. But the formula is returning 0 as the answer. The numbers are formatted as numbers. And the criteria is identical to the value in column A. Is there a bug with SUMIF?

[table and sumif formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bCOt.png)

Comment: Hard to tell what cells your formula refers to in your screen cap. Can you post a new one where we can see Columns and Rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your string starts with `<` or `>` you need to add the `=` to make it look at that as a character and not a mathematical operand:

```
=SUMIF(M21:M37,"=" & M39,N21:N37)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I had added ' in front of the < but that didn't work. This solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Tar glad to have helped.  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.